# How to connect to share point on premise server using azure logic apps or Azure data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps, sharepoint-2016

we have a share point installed on our organisation server. so I wanted to connect  to my organisations share point server using from azure logic app.
I have tried by installing on premise gateway in share point server buti'm unable to get the file path url from premise server.can any one help me with any link or process how to connect it?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can connect to on-premises data sources from Azure Logic Apps, download and install the on-premises data gateway on a local computer. The gateway works as a bridge that provides quick data transfer and encryption between data sources on premises (not in the cloud) and your logic apps.

Here are the [prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#prerequisites)

**[Steps to install data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#install-data-gateway)**

1. [Download, save, and run the gateway installer on a local computer](https://aka.ms/on-premises-data-gateway-installer).
2. Accept the default installation path, or specify the location on your computer where you want to install the gateway.
3. Review and accept the terms of use and privacy statement, and then choose Install.

[image]

4. After the gateway successfully installs, provide the email address for your work or school account, and choose Sign in.

[image]

5. Choose Register a new gateway on this computer > Next, which registers your gateway installation with the [gateway cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#gateway-cloud-service).

[image]

6. Provide this information for your gateway installation:

   - The name you want for your installation
   - The recovery key you want to create, which must have at least eight characters
   - Confirmation for your recovery key

[image]

7. Check the region selected for the gateway cloud service and Azure Service Bus that's used by your gateway installation.

[image]

8. To accept the default region, choose Configure. Or, to change the default region, follow these steps:

   - Next to the current region, select Change Region.
     [image]
   - On the next page, open the Select Region list, select the region you want, and choose Done.
     [image]
9. After the confirmation page appears, choose **Close**.
   The installer confirms that your gateway is now online and ready for use.

[image]

10. Now register your gateway in Azure by [creating an Azure resource for your gateway installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection).